# Going from .NET 3.5 to 4 seems to break legacy XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

In a legacy component I was troubleshooting, I stumbled across the following:

```
<CustomControls:DiscreteSlider x:Name="slider" Grid.Column="1">
  <CustomControls:DiscreteSlider.Value>
    <MultiBinding Mode="TwoWay">
      <MultiBinding.Converter>
        <WinConverters:FeatureConverter />
      </MultiBinding.Converter>
      <Binding Path="Enabled" />
      <Binding Path="Value" />
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:DialogBase}}" />
  </MultiBinding>
```

This was a binding for a slider-like user control ("DiscreteSlider") that had the following code in code behind (control actually wraps a slider and performs operations on it):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(DiscreteSlider),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((double)0.0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));

public double Value
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DiscreteSlider obj = d as DiscreteSlider;
    if (obj != null)
    {
        double oldValue = (double)e.OldValue;
        double newValue = (double)e.NewValue;
        obj._Slider.Value = newValue;
        obj.DoValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

And

```
private void Thumb_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _IsUserChange = true;
    Value = _Slider.Value;
}
```

What had been happening was that the value was not actually updating.  The `_Slider.Value` was set properly, but after Value was assigned to it, Value was unchanged.

The only thing that had changed about/around this code was that we had gone from .NET 3.5 to 4.0.  I was able to "fix" this by removing `Mode="TwoWay"` from the multibinding in XAML.  But, I cannot stand programming by coincidence.  I want to know why this happened.

Is anyone aware of an explanation as to why this XAML and code would be functional in 3.5 and not in 4?  If you can think of some other potential explanation, I'm open to hear it, but neither the XAML nor the code behind of that control has been changed since it was deployed (and functional) in 3.5.

**Edit**:

Here is the code for the value converter in question:

```
public class FeatureConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private bool Enabled = true;
    private const int MinValue = MelodyConst.MinValue;

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Count() < 2) return null;

        double returnValue = MelodyConst.DisabledValue;

        bool featureEnabled;
        Int32 featureValue;

        bool.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out featureEnabled);
        Int32.TryParse(values[1].ToString(), out featureValue);

        Enabled = featureEnabled;

        if (!featureEnabled)
            return returnValue;
        else
            returnValue = (double)(featureValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Int32 newSliderValue;
        Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out newSliderValue);

        object[] lsValues = new object[2];
        lsValues[0] = (object)Enabled;
        lsValues[1] = newSliderValue;

        return lsValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: You did have the FeatureConverter installed again?

Comment: Yes - the converter was there and behaving appropriately, when hit in debugger.

Comment: Can we see the code for FeatureConverter?

Comment: I just posted the converter's code.  Glancing through quickly, the only domain specific thing I see is MelodyConst, and all that represents is some hard-coded min value that gets applied to the slider when the slider is disabled (general idea is that slider can be modified normally, but if the object it represents is 'disabled' the slider goes to its minimum value and is disabled)

Comment: The Value property bound the multi-converter is a double, but you do an int.Parse in the converter, so this nearly always fails.  Shouldn't you be doing double.Parse(...) and casting to an int?

Comment: Actually, the "Value" property is an object, just to maximize the yuck factor.  Control treats it as a double and converter treats it as an int, but slider's interval is 1, so apparently this has not posed a problem at any point.  It did work, though I don't know if perhaps things got a little less lax in the new framework or something.  (And, btw, I didn't write any of this code -- I've just inherited the responsibility to fix the problem :( )

Comment: @ErikDietrich - Inheriting code sounds very familiar.....

Comment: As others have mentioned, the XAML parser was rewritten between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. FWIW I've found two bugs that cause a functional WPF 3.5 to crash when compiled for .NET 4: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544351/invalidcastexception-is-thrown-when-using-x-array-in-merged-resource-dictionary; https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573445/unknown-build-error-mc2000-referencing-public-struct-in-xaml-in-assembly-with-importedfromtypelib-attribute. It seems these regressions aren't uncommon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not personly experienced the problem that you ran into. But according to [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/26/wpf-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) the Xaml/Baml parser has been replaced with a new one in WPF 4.0. So it is entirely possible there are some breaking changes between 3.5 and 4.0, though I did not find any specific references to your problem.

From above blog.

> WPF 4 has replaced its implementation of XamlReader.Load(), BAML loading, Control & DataTemplates functionality with a new engine built on top of the new System.Xaml.dll.  As part of this effort, we’ve fixed many bugs and made many functionality improvements.

Comment: I think now we're talking.  Looking at the post, I neglected to mention that XAML in question occurs in a data template.  I didn't really think it mattered, but based on what you've posted here about new Control/Data Template functionality, I think we're narrowing it down.

Comment: Well, I actually spent all day looking into this since my 'fix' took care of part of the problem, but not all, as it turns out.  The exact reason is still unclear to me, but it's not going to matter in the end as, at this point, my course of action is likely going to be gutting this portion and refactoring its dependencies.  This post was most instrumental in informing my scorched earth decision, so I'm marking it as the answer.  With parser revamped a bizarre and awkward corner case like this is probably best reworked according to current best practices.  Thanks to you and all others.

Comment: You are welcome, it is always frustrating when code that used to work breaks because of changes outside of our control.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be happening because you have three values bound to the MultiValue converter but in the ConvertBack method you are returning only two values; can you try removing third binding as you are not using it anyways.

Something might have changed in 4.0 which causes the bindings to fail if converter doesn't returns correct number of params, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Good catch, but I deleted the extra parameter and still no joy.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try Erik; Can you post the code for your Enabled property too, is it having a public setter!